# Get Version of MLFlow model

Tags: mlflow

I'd like to get the actual version of a MLFlow model before loading / updating it to the running environment.
The environment access the by such paths: *models:/AICam/Production*
From time to time I need to reload the model. Unfortunately the models will be released asynchronously and loading take some minutes which interrupts the process.

Has anybody some hint how to do (in python)?

Comment: I found a solution, prob. there might be a better way but this work well
1st Get the Model from the Client
models = MlflowClient().get_registered_model(modelname)
filter to 'Production'
modelprod = [x for x in models.latest_versions if x.current_stage == 'Production']
now check for create-time

Comment: you can just use `client.get_latest_versions(name, ["Production"])`: https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.tracking.html#mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient.get_latest_versions

Answer (score -3):

You can pass the following to a variable to check for version. You can then test with if-then or assert statements.

```py
print(mlflow.__version__)
```